# Как изменить цвет шрифта в CSS?

Tags: css

В `header` нужно задать цвет шрифта. Написала:

```
header { color: cream; }
```

Сохранила как положено, но цвет шрифта не меняется.

Подскажите, что я могу делать не правильно?

Comment: вы не подключили файл с CSS

Comment: а также если у вас в header ссылки, чтобы применить к ссылкам цвет, который наследуется, надо написать `header a {color: inherit;}`

Answer (score 1):

```css
header {
  color: red;
}

header a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <p>Какой-то текст</p>
 <a href="https://css-tricks.com/">Ссылка</a>
</header>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <p>ololololo</p>
    </header>

  </body>
</html>
```

**master.css**

```
header p{
  color: red;
}
```

Проверьте правильность подключения CSS-файла.

Comment: Спасибо, файл подключен правильно. Только с цветом шрифта не разобралась) Сейчас попробую

Comment: @Виктория , если прямо все перепроверили, все подключено и прописано корректно, но все равно не работает, вполне возможен вариант с кэшем.  
В таком случае зайдите на вашу страницу в браузере и нажмите клавиши **Ctrl + Shift + R**. Бывает что стили не работают только из-за этого